# Нужна ли запятая в предложении перед «где»?

Tags: пунктуация

Фраза «Паркуюсь где хочу», то есть везде... Это выражение типа как «все что угодно»? Или нужна запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Розеналь, § 41.2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146):

> Выражения с глаголом *хотеть*, образующие цельные по смыслу выражения,
> запятой не разделяются.

Хоть приведённый вами оборот не входит в розенталевский список, но аналогия очевидна. Да и [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=299197) подтверждает.